# If $A^{k+1}=0$ and $A^k \ne 0$, which of the following statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A^{k+1}=0$ and $A^k \ne 0$, which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1. $A$ is singular
> 2. The eigenvalues of $A$ are all zero
> 3. The eigenvalues of $A^k$ are all zero

I think 1 is true because

$$\det(A^{k+1})=(\det(A))^{k+1}=0\Longrightarrow \det(A)=0$$

2 is true because $A$ satisfies polynomial $x^{k+1}=0$. Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^{k+1}=0$, all roots of $m_A(x)$ have to be zeros.

But I am not sure about statement 3. Let $B = A^k$. If I know that $A^k = 3I$, then I know that $A^k$ will have $3$ as one of its eigenvalue because $A^k = 3I$ is translated into $x - 3=0$. But here, it just says $A^k \ne 0$ so I am confused.

Comment: If $Ax=\lambda x$ then $A^kx=\lambda^kx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, $k$ is an integer and $k \geq 1$.

Note that
$$
[A^{k}]^2 = A^{2k} = A^{k-1}A^{k+1} = A^{k-1}(0) = 0
$$
So, $A^k$ satisfies the polynomial $x^2 = 0$.

---

In general, it is worth knowing that for any polynomial $p$: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$.  Conversely, if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$, then there exists an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ for which $p(\lambda) = \mu$.